# add border to pdf page using itext

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

this is my source code. why am I not able to add border to my pdf page even after enabling borders for all sides? I've set border and its color too still I'm not able to add border.

```
void create() throws DocumentException,IOException{
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
        document.setMargins(36, 72, 108, 180);
        document.setMarginMirroring(false);
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(36,108);
        rect.enableBorderSide(1);
        rect.enableBorderSide(2);
        rect.enableBorderSide(4);
        rect.enableBorderSide(8);
        rect.setBorder(2);
        rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        document.add(rect);
         Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 26, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Paragraph title= new Paragraph("CURRICULUM VITAE\n\n",font);
        title.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(title);
        Font f1= new Font (Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 13, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Paragraph info= new Paragraph("Name\n\nEmail\n\nContact Number",f1);
        Paragraph addr= new Paragraph("Street\n\nCity\n\nPin",f1);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.spacingAfter();
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(info);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);
        cell.setExtraParagraphSpace(1.5f);
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(addr);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        cell.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);
        cell.setExtraParagraphSpace(1.5f);
        table.addCell(cell);
        document.add(table);
        document.add(new Chunk("\n"));
        document.add(new LineSeparator(2f,100,BaseColor.DARK_GRAY,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,-1f));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You didn't define a border width.
2. You're adding the border only once. What if you want the border to appear on every page?

You can fix (1.) by adding:

```
rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
rect.setBorderWidth(2);
```

Note that I would remove the `enableBorderSide()` calls. You'll notice that you've used the `setBorder()` method in the wrong way.

To fix (2.), I would use a page event. Note that you can't use `document.add()` in a page event, so you'll have to do something as described in the [`DrawRectangle`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/DrawRectangle) example that was written in answer to the question [iText: PdfContentByte.rectangle(Rectangle) does not behave as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718712/itext-pdfcontentbyte-rectanglerectangle-does-not-behave-as-expected)

You didn't define a page size when creating the `Document` object, which means that iText will be using `PageSize.A4`. A couple of lines later, you use `PageSize.LETTER`. These values are immutable `Rectangle` objects. You can create a new `Rectangle` using the dimensions/coordinates of `PageSize.A4` (or in your case: `PageSize.LETTER`). You can obtain the dimensions using the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` method and the coordinates using `getLeft()`, `getBottom()`, `getRight()` and `getTop()`.

Comment: how to add border as the size of page. I'm using letter as page size, so what parameters should be passed?

Comment: I've updated my answer. This will give you an idea on how to get the parameters you need to create the `Rectangle` you want to use to draw a border.

Comment: thanx I got it :)
if I add bordr at every new page then will there be any problem?
or can you please tell me which method to use to add border to entire pdf?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you don't know when a new page will be added. Sure, you know when you manually use `document.newPage()`, but in some cases iText starts a new page automatically when content doesn't fit on the current page. That's why you should add the border in the `onEndPage()` method of a page event.

Comment: table.addCell(String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()));
this is how we add table to each page... what is the corresponding method for adding rectangle?

Comment: this method is for adding table, I want corresponding method for rectangle in page event so that I won't need 2 add page border again and again.......
or is there any method for adding solid border??

Comment: btw I read your book 3-4 days back... amazing author you are... Reading is not my cup of tea but I loved reading your book.. the way you explain things is very simple and interesting too! :)

Comment: I want corresponding method for rectangle in page event so that I won't need 2 add page border again and again....... or is there any method for adding solid border??

Comment: Adding a rectangle can be done with the `rectangle()` method, but I don't think I understand the question. You're already adding a table: I see `table.addCell()` in your question. Why not define a border for the cell? Then you don't have to worry about adding it yourself.

Comment: Adding a border in the `onEndPage()` event is just a matter of copying some code from the example I mentioned ( http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/DrawRectangle ) into the body of the `onEndPage()` method.

Comment: is there any method in itext than render pdf in a jframe?

Comment: iText is about creating PDF, not about rendering PDF, not about Swing components, so the answer is: no, that's out of scope for iText.

Comment: The answer is no, that's out of scope for iText.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(577,825,18,15); // you can resize rectangle 
     rect.enableBorderSide(1);
     rect.enableBorderSide(2);
     rect.enableBorderSide(4);
     rect.enableBorderSide(8);
     rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
     rect.setBorderWidth(1);
     document.add(rect);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a border on all pages of a PDF file, then use this method.

```
val document = Document()
val writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, FileOutputStream(filePath))
writer.pageEvent = MyEvent()
```

Class of MyEvent declared separately.

```
class MyEvent: PdfPageEventHelper() {
        override fun onEndPage(writer: PdfWriter?, document: Document?) {
            super.onEndPage(writer, document)
            addBorder(document)
        }

        private fun addBorder(document: Document?) {
            val rect = Rectangle(577f, 825f, 18f, 15f) // you can resize rectangle
            rect.border = Rectangle.BOX
            rect.borderWidth = 1f
            document!!.add(rect)
        }
}
```